# Closed form for this power series looking like an hypergeometric?

Tags: summation, recurrence-relations, closed-form, hypergeometric-function

I would like to "resum" the following expression:

$$\sum_{k=0}^a \frac{(-a)_k (-b)_k}{(c)_k} x^k\,, \tag{1}$$

with $a, b, c$ positive even numbers and $x > 0$ real. Is there a known function for this finite sum? Wolfram Alpha and Mathematica return a [DifferenceRoot system](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%20Pochhammer%5B-a%2Ck%5DPochhammer%5B-b%2Ck%5D%2F%28Pochhammer%5Bc%2Ck%5D%29%20x%5Ek%20from%20k%3D0%20to%20k%3Da).

Note that if there was a $k!$ in the denominator, this would be a hypergeometric function $_2F_1(a,b,c,x)$, as explained [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function#The_hypergeometric_series).

Answer (score 2):

Okay I am stupid: This can be brought into the form of a generalised hypergeometric function by multiplying the argument of the sum by $\frac{k!}{k!} = \frac{(1)_k}{k!}$, and then we find that eq. $(1)$ is the same as:

$$_3F_1 (-a,-b,1;c;x)\,. \tag{2}$$